# How to remove wrong values in the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has multiple columns and I am interested to take one column out of it and create a new dataframe with that column.
My dataframe is

```
category_id category_name   channel_id
24  Entertainment   UCv1ZjbkebUwVOJCgtstOBZQ
```

I am creating a new dataframe as want the category_id in it to create 10k rows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'category_id': [df['category_id'] for x in range(10000)]})
df1.head()
```

This creates a dataframe with 10k rows however the value that I am getting into the dataframe
is

```
category_id
0   178 10 215 10 251 10 312 1...
1   178 10 215 10 251 10 312 1...
2   178 10 215 10 251 10 312 1...
3   178 10 215 10 251 10 312 1...
4   178 10 215 10 251 10 312 1...
```

which is wrong as I wanted the values like

```
category_id
0   10
1   10
2   10
3   10
4   10
```

I made changes to this dataframe by removing the list comprehension from `df5 = pd.DataFrame({'category_id': df4['category_id'] for x in range(10000)})
df5.head()` it solved this error but that didn't create 10k records.
What can be done over to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
print (df)
   category_id  category_name                channel_id
0           10  Entertainment  UCv1ZjbkebUwVOJCgtstOBZQ
1           24  Entertainment  UCv1ZjbkebUwVOJCgtstOBZQ
```

---

```
N = 5
df5 = df['category_id'].repeat(N).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
print (df5)
   category_id
0           10
1           10
2           10
3           10
4           10
5           24
6           24
7           24
8           24
9           24
```